# Cannot launch SDK manager

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-virtual-device

```
Cannot launch SDK manager.
```

Output:

> '"C:\Users\ILYASK~1\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib\find_java64.exe"
>   -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.. ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to
>   properly use the Android Developer Tools, you need a suitable version
>   of Java JDK installed on your system. We recommend that you install
>   the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
>   oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads
>
> If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME
>   environment variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System
>   Settings to point to the JDK folder.
>
> You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
>   developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

I tried all solutions given in other questions but nothing woks for me
Output :

[image]

environment variables :

[image]

Comment: you sure you installed x64 version of java

Comment: yes I installed everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK , the problem is solved :

1. Install JAVA JDK
2. define the JAVA_HOME environment variable
3. Install Android Studio on C:\SDK (not the default directory)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Environment variable settings.It should contain Java_Home and directory of executable else please set and try.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `x64` bit of java installed, also try adding this environmental variable to system:

```
ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75
```

[image]